# I am trying to implement a like button in nodejs app.I used span to update number of likes.when the button clicked, number in span increments weirdly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I don't know what is the error in my node.js app.

```js
$('.like').on('click', () => {
  let val = parseInt($('.likes').text());
  console.log(val);
  $('.likes').text(val + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="like"> 
  <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
  <span class="likes">0</span>
</button>
```

when i click the button, value in span increments weirdly

[image: Image of error]

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: https://plnkr.co/edit/v3vUxZZd1zNLJhW75RYA?p=preview

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me. I get +1 every time I hit the button in your example

Comment: Did you see the image I shared. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can observe this in your application

once you clicked on the like button, initially count is increasing from `0 + 1 -> 1`, and its updating the value to both the like button.

on clicking again, its taking both the `likes` button value and concatenate them to produce `11` and it adds 1 to produce 12, `11 + 1 -> 12`

Third time value will be concatenated text of both the `likes` button value `1212` and adding 1 results `1213`. `1212 + 1 -> 1213`

You are getting this result because both `cards` in your application are same in all respects and every `div's` and `class` names are same.

You need to use different `id` to these cards buttons to avoid this conflict. Also as @Paul specified increasing its scope with the surrounding div's will also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i Think it’s because your selector is matching all your like buttons, not just the one you clicked. Change your click handlers first line to use ‘$(‘.likes’, this)’ to scope it to just the current like button.